# applescript close tab in safari

Tags: safari, applescript

with

```
tell application "Safari"
        set winlist to every window
        repeat with win in winlist
                set tablist to every tab in win
                repeat with t in tablist
                        name of t as string
                end repeat
        end repeat
end tell
```

I can get the name of safari tab

how I can close a tab with a specific name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t
            if name starts with "autom" then close
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

`tell application "Safari" to close documents where name starts with "autom"` would close all windows that contain tabs that start with `autom`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set winlist to count of every window
    repeat with i from 1 to winlist
        close (every tab of window i whose name = "Google")
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: It works, but throws odd error: execution error: Safari got an error: Can’t get item 20 of every tab of every window. Invalid index. (-1719). Suppose that the winlist index is not correct once it closes the tab. Ehem, yes, I have easily 20 tabs open :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me 2
Neither of them work
The strange thing is, it does work when the safari is not in fullscreen 
I guess it is a bug in safari